# Pytorch Matrix Input single Output

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to build a Neural Network that predicts a single value in a time series.
For this I have multiple inputs for every time t until (t-100).
For every t I have about 20 values that can be used to predict a single output for t+1.

So example Input matrix:

Target, Info1, Info2...

1,2,2

1,3,2

2,3,3

4,5,5
....

This would be one Input Matrix.

As an Output I would like to have an estimate for the next Target Value.

Now my question:
How do I define this for Input and Output so that PyTorch gets that it should use the whole matrix to predict Target Output (not predicting infos) at t+1.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for batching. By default, neural networks in `pytorch` (at least the builtins) have batching enabled, and the matrix you're describing should just work. If it doesn't, if you share your code it will be easier to tell you where to go from there.